# listing datas with conditions from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, list, sql-order-by

I have a problem that hard to explain, but i will try. First, i want to say what i am trying to do. I have two tables, "Author" has author id, author nick and author type. "Entries" has entry id, entry topic, entry content and entry's author.
(There are 2 types of authors: -normal and -banned)

At first, i was using this query to list topics:

```
"SELECT distinct topic FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $l1, $lim";
```

But i have a problem. I want the query to list the topics ordering by normal-authors' last entry id's, which means ignoring all banned-authors' entries.

I tried several different codes, but all i can manage was listing the topics that the last author isn't banned. So it caused ignoring the topics entered by banned-authors even it has normal-authors inside.

I want you to help me to write the query that can able to manage this example:

> topic list: a b c d

If a normal author entered to topic 'c', the list shold be

> c a b d

And banned author entered to topic 'b', the list should be

> c a b d

not

> c a d

I know i couldn't explain my whole expectations, but all i want is writing a query, using this two tables, getting author type from author table where author name = entry's author, and listing the topics (distinct) ordering by non-banned authors' entries. Thank you.

Comment: Can there be multiple entries with the same entry id? One for each author?

Comment: no, entry id's are primary key. authors has no limits or rules for enrtries. they can write limitless entries on same or different topics.

Comment: So how do you know that the different entries belong together?

Comment: i didn't get you questions but when user clicks a topic on topic list, he goes to show.php?t=$topic and entries lists by entry topic names, ordering entry id.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM topic inner join entries on topic.topicID = entries.topicID
WHERE entries.entryID in 
         (Select Max(entryID) 
          From entries inner join authors on entries.authorID = authors.authorID
          Where author.authorType = 'normal'
          Group By topicID) 
ORDER BY entries.entryID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  e.topic
FROM entries e
  LEFT JOIN authors a ON a.id = e.author
GROUP BY
  e.topic
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(MIN(a.type), '') = 'banned',
  e.topic
```